# Anyone have a link for this Duden book?

Tags: learning, resource, dictionary, book

Today, I am going to what will hopefully be the first of many tandem speaking sessions. (I am a native English speaker, and my partner is German.)

I am hoping that I can find online a book that I remember seeing somewhere. It was published by Duden, and it was quite thick -- probably at least more than 300 pages, I would conservatively guess. Each page or set of pages featured a detailed, black and white drawing of a scene, and each page included vocabulary for that scene.

So, for example, one page featured a kitchen, with the bottom half of the page identifyng all the things in the kitchen. Another page featured a farm scene, with the vocabulary for the equipment. As I said, there were hundreds of these pages, featuring some very specialized vocabulary.

**Does anyone have a link for this book? I would love to buy a copy so that my partner and I can really stretch our capabilities.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean this one:

> ### [Duden Bildwörterbuch](https://shop.duden.de/Shop/Das-Bildworterbuch-1)

There is also the [Duden Bildwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache](https://shop.duden.de/Shop/Duden-Das-Bildworterbuch-Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache-Fur-Alltag-und-Arbeit). However, I think it differs from your description because it has coloured photographs instead of black-and-white drawings and not so much specialized vocabulary.